# Daily Email update to admin about Newly added product information

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, email-reminders, new-products

I am having multi-vendor store where one sub-admin add the product and main-admin take care of configuration, tax, shipping etc.

Now the main admin needed email notification at the end of the day about newly added products by the sub-admin, in that day.

I am not cleared with that how can I send email to main admin at the end of the day with newly added product information.?

Sending a mail is not a problem but getting newly added products at the end of day is not cleared for me.

I thought, It can be done by CRON Job, I need to create script that run at the end of the day, The script contains code to get newly added product by comparing created_at date of each product,

Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your valuable responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for doing this would be as suggested.

1. Create a new module,
2. This new module will have a cron task that runs each night,
3. This cron task will use the product collection and filter by `created_at` date so that you know all the new products for the last 24 hours,
4. Send an email you can simply use the Zend_Mail class for this and send an email will all ids or whatever the admin expects to get,
5. You could load the email address from the Magento admin user, you could also set this via system.xml if you want or simply hard code it (not the best option)

Nice and simply really